# The method to prove that empty set is symmetric is also applicable to prove that it is nonsymmetric?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

One of my friends offered this kind of puzzle which I cannot resolve for hours:

"
(1) “If E is empty, E is symmetric.”

“E is empty” is true. We assume this. Does it follow that E is symmetric? By definition of symmetry, if xRy, then yRx. Because the antecedent is false (there are no elements in empty set), the entire conditional statement is true.

(2) “If E is empty, E is asymmetric.”

“E is empty” is true. We assume this. Does it follow that E is asymmetric? By definition of asymmetry, if xRy, then ynotRx. Because the antecedent is false (there are no elements in empty set), the entire conditional statement is true.

Then we have “If E is empty, E is both symmetric and asymmetric”. BUT if xRy does implies yRx, it CANNOT be the case that xRy implies ynotRx.

What is wrong here?"

Comment: There is nothing wrong there, if you formalize it propperly using quantifiers you will see there is no contradiction. From proving the empty set is symmetric and asymmetric you can not derive that result for any set. Your conclution should be $\forall x,y \in \emptyset (xRy \implies (yRx \land \lnot yRx))$ which is true because there are no $x,y$ in $\emptyset$ so you can't prove its falsity. But it doesn't generalizes to any set for obvious reasons

Comment: You mean the empty binary relation (the relation with no ordered couples inside)?

Comment: Actually, no, I mean the empty set, $\emptyset$.

Comment: But symmetry is a property of relations, not of sets

Comment: In the title you say "nonsymmetric", this is different from "asymmetric", a relation can be "nonsymmetric" if it fails to be symmetric in just one case, not in any case

Comment: Let me redo my comment to use the empty *relation*, which is actually the very same thing as the empty set: by Extensionality, at most one set has no members. Yes, they're both true. (By the way, $\emptyset$ is also transitive.) IF $(x,y)\in E = \emptyset$ — and that's a "big if" — then $(y,x)\in E$, and also $(y,x)\notin E = \emptyset$, That is, $xEy\to(yEx\land\neg yEx)$. Writing it in terms of $\emptyset$ makes clear that there's no problem:
$$∀x,y[ (x,y)\in\emptyset\to ((y,x)\in\emptyset \land (y,x)\notin\emptyset) ]
$$
The antecedent is always false, so the consequent can be anything.